# When to choose std::vector over std::map for key-value data?

Tags: c++

Considering the positive effect of caching and data locality when searching in primary memory, I tend to use `std::vector<>` with `std::pair<>`-like key-value items and perform linear searches for both, if I know that the total amount of key-value items will never be "too large" to severely impact performance.

Lately I've been in lots of situations where I know beforehand that I *will* have huge amounts of key-value items and have therefore opted for `std::map<>` from the beginning.

I'd like to know how you make your decisions for the proper container in situations like the ones described above.

Do you

- always use `std::vector<>` (or similar)?
- always use `std::map<>` (or similar)?
- have a gut feeling for where in the item-count range one is preferable over the other?
- something entirely different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I only rarely use `std::vector` with a linear search (except in conjunction with binary searching as described below). I suppose for a small enough amount of data it would be better, but with that little data it's unlikely that anything is going to provide a huge advantage.

Depending on usage pattern, a binary search on an `std::vector` can make sense though. A `std::map` works well when you need to update the data regularly during use. In quite a few cases, however, you load up some data and then you use the data -- but after you've loaded the data, it mostly remains static (i.e., it changes very little, if at all).

In this case, it can make a lot of sense to load the data into a vector, sort it if necessary, and then do binary searches on the data (e.g. `std::lower_bound`, `std::equal_range`). This gives pretty much the best of both worlds -- low-complexity binary searches *and* good cache usage from high locality of reference (i.e., the vector is contiguous, as opposed to the linked structure of a `std::map`). The shortcoming, of course, is that insertions and deletions are slow -- but this is one time I have used your original idea -- store newly inserted data separately until it reaches some limit, and only then sort it in with the rest of the data, so a single search consists of a binary search of the main body of the data, followed by a linear search of the (small amount) of newly inserted data.

Answer (score 5):

I would never make the choice solely on (possibly bogus) "efficiency" grounds, but always on what I am actually going to do with the container. Do I want to store duplicates? Is insertion order important? Will I sometimes want to search for the value not the key? Those kind of things.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using sorted data structures?  They tend to offer logarithmic searches and inserts - a reasonable trade-off.  Personally I don't have any hard and fast rules other than liking maps for the ability to key on a human-readable/understandable value.

Of course there's plenty of discussion as well on the efficiency of maps vs. lists/vectors (sorted and unsorted) - if your key is a string that's 10,000 characters, it can take longer to do a string compare than to search through a list of just a few items, so you want to make sure that you can efficiently compare keys as well.

Answer (score 2):

I almost always prefer to use map (or unordered_map, when a hash container makes more sense) vs. a vector.

That being said, I think your reasoning is backwards.  I would tend to use a vector *only* when there are huge amounts of data, since a vector will be a smaller memory footprint.

With the right kinds of datasets, you can load a vector and then sort it and binary_search it with a smaller footprint and similar performance characteristics to a map, especially if the dataset is stable after load.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not taking `unordered_map` into account?

Comment: @Nemanja: Because I generally work in a severely crippled Windows CE / Mobile environment where TR1 would be too time consuming, to say the least, to integrate.